# Combine model fields

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to add a field to a read-only database. So, I would like to create a dummy database of the form;

```
class ReadOnly(models.Model):
    first =  models.CharField(db_column='First')
    second = models.CharField(db_column='Second')

class ExtraStuff(models.Model):
    first =  models.CharField(db_column='First')
    second = models.CharField(db_column='Second')
    combined = first+second
```

I have used the @property but as I cannot combine properties and filters I feel like this is a better solution. However, I am out of ideas for how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying a getter for combine ?

```
class ExtraStuff(models.Model):
    first =  models.CharField(db_column='First')
    second = models.CharField(db_column='Second')

    @property
    def combined(self):
        return self.first + self.second
```

Comment: The problem with this and the solution posted by Daniel van Flymen is that I cannot use this value in a filter. When I attempt this, a FieldError is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but if you just want to get combined fields:

```
class ExtraStuff(models.Model):
    first =  models.CharField(db_column='First')
    second = models.CharField(db_column='Second')

@property
def combined(self)
    return self.first + self.second
```

Then when you have your model, you can treat combined as a read-only field:

```
my_model = ExtraStruff.objects.get(pk=1)
my_model.combined
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [annotate() and concat()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) and then filter().

```
ReadOnly.objects.annotate(combined=Concat('first', 'second', output_field=CharField())).filter(combined='abc123')
```

You may add a custom manager to your ReadOnly model to avoid code repetition

```
class ReadOnlyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ReadOnlyManager, self).get_queryset().annotate(combined=Concat('first', 'second', output_field=CharField()))

class ReadOnly(models.Model):
    first =  models.CharField(db_column='First')
    second = models.CharField(db_column='Second')
    objects = models.Manager()
    combined_objects = ReadOnlyManager()
```

Then you can use the following anywhere in your code.

```
ReadOnly.combined_objects.filter(combined='abc123')
```